# How to use webpack HotModuleReplacementPlugin to build two html website

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I use webpack HotModuleReplacementPlugin to let my website could hot reload when I fix the code.

But I don't know how to build two html page.

I want to build two page "index.html" & "introduction.html"

Now I use these code in my webpack.config.js but it will have a problem, in the Chrome dev tool would show

「Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.」

How could I solved these problem?

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var config = {
  entry: {
    index: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx')
    ],
    introduction: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/introduction.jsx')
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publishPath: '/',
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:/\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'react-hot!babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        execlude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss!sass'
      },{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        execulde: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss!sass'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file?name=images/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [
    autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions']})
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  exclude: [
    /(test)/
  ],
  devServer: {
    contenBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/html/index.html'

    }),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'introduction.html',
      template: './src/html/introduction.html'

    }),

  ]
}

module.exports = config;
```